# Do a action on Value change event of h:input Text only

Tags: jsf, jstl

In my scenario i have a h:inputText, and i have added a valueChangeListener property to it, and the value Change Event is implemented in the bean. When submit the form, even then the  valuechangeListener is getting invoked. But i require, value change listener to only run, when i do changes on the input text. Please help me with this.

Does the h:inputText fire the valuChangeListener only when, the page is submitted??

Answer (score 0):

The value only changes at the browser. The server doesn't get to know about it until you submit the form, unless you can add some AJAX processing. JSF 2 has AJAX facilities.